# Handsontable sorting column alphanumeric

Tags: sorting, handsontable, alphanumeric

This is about Handsontable plugin

I want to sort a colunm that contains both letters and numbers in a string.. But IMO its odd the way it prioritize the numbers.

It sorts like this:

a1
a4
aa
ab
aj
c1
c9
cd
cn
k1
kk

In my terminology it should be sorting like this:

aa
ab
aj
a1
a4
cd
cn
c1
c9
kk
k1

(this websites detroys the breaks bestween each 2 char "row/string")

Comment: I see how its sorting my column. Im asking for someone that knows about Handsontable, I'v even tagged it with Handsontable..

Comment: In DB2/AS400 letters comes before digits, thats why im asking for a solution for Handsontable

Comment: @AP87 To have the column contents appear more like a column, you can preserve line breaks by adding two spaces after each item, or by indenting the items by four spaces like you would for a code snippet. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: @SeantheBean: Yes, it was *my* mistake. I didn't notice the tag until AP87 told me. Thanks anyway for telling me *again*. I've learned my lesson and removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any pre-built sorting functions that don't prioritize numbers.. That's unusual, but I can understand the limitations of working with systems with unusual limitations.

Personally, I find that a natural sorting algorithm (which handles numbers as numeric values, rather than as character values) generally produces the best user experience. Check out http://phpjs.org/functions/natsort/ and http://phpjs.org/functions/natcasesort/ if you're interested.

But back to your current problem. I think you'll have to write your own comparator function in order to create the sorting functionality you described. Something like:

```
function db2StringSort(a, b) {
    // as long as there is string to compare, compare it
    var i = 0;
    while (a[i] !== undefined && b[i] !== undefined) {
        // if the characters are the same, move on to the next
        if (a[i] === b[i]) {
            i += 1;
            continue;
        }

        // if a contains a number, prioritize b, and vice versa
        if (a[i].match(/\d/)) {
            if (!b[i].match(/\d/)) {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (b[i].match(/\d/)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        // maybe check punctuation or special characters, if they need special handling?

        // next compare characters to characters and digits to digits
        if (a[i] > b[i]) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
            return -1;
        }

        // we already checked if they're the same, so it should never get here
    }

    // if the compared parts of the strings are the same, prioritize the shorter one
    // (if the length is the same, then they're equivalent, return 0)
    return a.length - b.length;
}

source.sort(db2StringSort);
```

If you need fancier handling (like making it case insensitive or handling special characters) you might be better off starting from the source for http://phpjs.org/functions/strnatcasecmp/, and modifying it as needed.

Unfortunately, it seems Handsontable does not yet support using custom comparator functions for sorting (see https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/593 and http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/demo-sorting-data.html), so you would need to apply the sorting outside of Handsontable, and then pass the sorted data in.

If that doesn't suit your needs, it may be possible to create your own plugin and use that instead of the `columnSorting` plugin, but that would likely require a lot more work.